# how to avoid server busy window in enterprise architect

Tags: python-2.7, add-in, enterprise-architect

I have created an addin(Extension) for enterprise architect. The addin basically popup's a dialog(using tkinter of python to show this popup) where i allow the user to select the directory path. now if the user takes more than say 3 seconds, there appears an server busy window, which the user has to click switch to to return to the previous control. Is there any way to avoid this or increase the server busy timeout in EA?. The dialog popup and server busy window appears like below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the solution, Since EA is an 32bit application, even if you are using 64bit windows. You are expected to install python 32bit.